# Searching value in a dataframe and then putting corresponding value from dictionary in a new coloumn

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has a column of name.I have another dictionary which has names as keys and values associated with it.I want to search a name in dataframe and add corresponding value from dictionary in a new coloumn.

```
my dictionary   
fruits={'mango':1,'apple':2,'guava':0,'nut':1}

my dataframe
Fruit
mango
apple
guava
nut
```

Expected Output

```
  Fruit  Frequency
    mango   1
    apple   2
    guava   0
    nut     1
```

The data frame is already there.I just want to map the values with the corresponding element

Also if my Dictionary has more key-value pair than my original dataframe How can I add the keys and corresponding values to dataframe.

Suppose if my dataframe is

```
Fruit 
mango
apple
```

And now I would like to have just nut and not guava because it has value 0

So expected output would be

```
Fruit  Count
mango  1
apple  2
nut    1
```

Comment: Okay, wonderful. Where is your data? Why isn't it in your question? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry I was new to the forum

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Okay, this is a duplicate. You need `map` or `replace`.

Comment: `df.Fruit.map(my_dictionary)`

Comment: On a side note can you tell if my dictionary is having more elements and I will like to add the one's which are not in my original dataframe How can i do that

Comment: Hmm, that's a different question. If you edit your question with this information / new data that describes your problem, I can reopen your question.

Comment: Yeah i have edited the question with new data

Comment: Can you explain this? `How can I add the keys and corresponding values to dataframe.` It seems to describe something different from what your data shows.

Comment: Now in my dataframe Nut is not there.But my dictionary has it.So for that Nut should get added in my dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part, use `map`/`replace`  -

```
df

   Fruit
0  mango
1  apple
2  guava
3    nut

df['Frequency'] = df.Fruit.map(fruits)
```

---

```
df['Frequency'] = df.Fruit.replace(fruits)   # alternative to map
```

---

```
df

   Fruit  Frequency
0  mango          1
1  apple          2
2  guava          0
3    nut          1
```

---

For the second part, you can perform a set difference and concatenate with the original -

```
df

Fruit 
mango
apple

i = df.Fruit
j = pd.Series(list(set(fruits.keys()).difference(i)))

df = pd.concat([i, j], ignore_index=True).to_frame('Fruit')
df

   Fruit
0  mango
1  apple
2    nut
3  guava
```

---

To drop rows with Frequency == 0, use boolean indexing -

```
df

   Fruit  Frequency
0  mango          1
1  apple          2
2  guava          0
3    nut          1

df = df[df.Frequency.gt(0)]
df

   Fruit  Frequency
0  mango          1
1  apple          2
3    nut          1
```

Alternatively, use `eval`/`query`.

```
df.query("Frequency > 0")

   Fruit  Frequency
0  mango          1
1  apple          2
3    nut          1
```